# scanner input, double do while loop

Tags: java

I need some help with using a `do while` loop for an input with scanner. When the incorrect value is entered, I want an error message to display and then be forced to re enter a value. At the moment it shows the error message but continues to proceed onwards.

```
double price;
do { 
  System.out.print("What is the price of " + name + "? ");
  price = (double) input.nextDouble();
  if (price <= 0) {
    System.out.println("Error - burgers must be over $0");
  }
} while (price < 0);
input.nextLine(); // flush input line
```

Comment: You use two different conditions: `price <= 0` to print the error message, and `price < 0` to loop, try changing `price < 0` to `price <= 0` in the `while` statement

Comment: Actually you don't need this inner `if` and need to change the `while` to `price >= 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Just chage the `do-while` condition form

```
while (price < 0);
```

to

```
 while (price <= 0);
```

as your current while condition is only chekcing for values less than 0.